# Will My Game Crash If I Remove Admob Ad Unit?

Tags: google-play, admob

I recently published a game on google play. There are 2 types of ad units in my game. One is Banner and the other is interstitial. I don't want to make changes to the script and submit it again. Because that's why I've been waiting for a long time for confirmation. If I remove the banner ad I created through the Google AdMob site, will my game crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it shouldn't crash if you remove the Ad unit.

But another way to do this (if you want to enable it later) is to set an `Manual eCPM floor` to 1000$ for the banner ad, this will make the ad only appear if the price is very very high (which is almost never happen).

You can also show the banner in one country only using `mediation` with setting the floor to 1000$ too.